# Mapping in Entity Framework slow

Tags: performance, entity-framework, mapping

I have a query that I'm not sure how to increase performance to.

I can see in EF-Profiler that the sql query takes 154 ms, which is fine since the DB is in the cloud. The problem is the mapping that is being done with the result by EF. That takes a total time of 2801 ms. 
This is althou a big question with a total of 3698 rows fetched.

What should I do to increase the mapping speed of EF? My question looks like:

```
var parcels =
                            context.Parcels.Include("ParcelStatusLogs")
                                .Include("Comments")
                                .Include("Comments.CommentStatu")
                                .Where(p => p.CarrierDateSent >= dateFrom.Date &&
                                         p.CarrierDateSent <= dateTo.Date &&
                                         p.ClientCompanyID == user.ComapanyID &&
                                         (p.IsActive == true || p.IsActive == isActive))
                                .OrderBy(r => r.CarrierDateSent).ThenByDescending(p => p.ParcelStatusLogs.OrderByDescending(
                                f => f.ParcelStatusID).FirstOrDefault().ParcelStatusID).ThenBy(p =>p.ParcelStatusLogs.OrderBy(f =>f.ParcelStatusEventDate).FirstOrDefault().ParcelStatusEventDate)
```

Should I consider going outside of EF, and using something else?

Thanks

Comment: How does the time change if you use pre-compiled query? Anyway with fetchign 4k records you can expect that materialization into objects (using reflection internally) will take some time.

Comment: I tried pre-compiled, but didn't gain much performance. Do you think I will gain any performace moving it to views and doing manuall mapping, or even writing my own sql, and mapping with an old datareader?

Comment: Yes you will get much better performance with old plain ADO.NET and SQL.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Since I've used EF through my entire solution, how would you recommend me to implement the plain sql, to keep some structure? Prefably views or, how would you have done it?

Comment: First start by using the simplest possible solution to verify that it really helps = `SqlDataReader` and `SqlCommand` to get all data you need.